# Numerical integration takes huge time to run

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics

```
N1 = 500;
sd1 = 0.02;
sd2 = 0.08;
h = 0.5;
x0 = 1/( N1);
tp = 150;
 si[t_] := If[Mod[Quotient[t, tp] , 2] == 0 , sd1, sd2];
 taui[t_] := 2 \!\(
 \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(t\)]\(si[
    t1] \[DifferentialD]t1\)\);
   pf1 = ( 1/(1 + NIntegrate[(E^-taui[t]), {t, 0, Infinity}]));

  C1 = 2 N1 pf1;

  B[Te_] := (2 N1)/NIntegrate[E^taui[t], {t, 0, Te}];

 pdfgenh[Te] = (C1  B[Te]^2)/(2 N1) E^ 
  taui[Te] NIntegrate[q^-1 E^(-B[Te] q) E^(-C1 q^-1), {q, 0, 1000}];
   NIntegrate[Te pdfgenh[Te], {Te, 1, 1000}]
```

The above integral take huge time to run. Please resolve this issue.

Comment: Your `si[t_] := If[Mod[Quotient[t, tp] , 2] == 0 , sd1, sd2]` is equal to `sd2` for [almost all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_all) values of `t`, which means that `taui[t_] = 2 sd2 t` and `pf1 = 2 sd2/(1 + 2 sd2)`, etc. until the end. No need for numerical integration.

Comment: @Roman I think `si[t]` is a squarewave. `taui[t]` follows to `t (sd1 + sd2) - (sd2 -sd1) tp (2 UnitTriangle[(Mod[t, 2 tp] - tp)/( tp 2)] - 1)`

Comment: Ah yes you're right.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Could you please suggest how to resolve this issue? yes it is a square wave

Comment: @SachinKaushik That only simplifies the defintion of `taui[t]` but doesn't(currently...) answer your question.